# xlwings v0.20.4 installed instead of v0.20.5

Tags: xlwings

I'm attempting to install the latest version of xlwings v0.20.5 (released 8/27/2020) on a Windows 10 machine.

After running the following two commands at the Anaconda prompt,

```
conda install xlwings
xlwings addin install
```

v0.20.4 is instead installed.

Is v0.20.5 available via conda or is the xlwings website mistaken when it states that v0.20.5 is the latest available version?

Comment: 0.20.5 is not yet available via conda: https://anaconda.org/search?q=xlwings but via https://pypi.org/project/xlwings/

Comment: Thank you. Is there an eta on conda availability?

Comment: it's not available via conda-forge